# Missing KeywordModelData from a Dynamic Component using Session Content Model

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, java, dxa-2.0

We use SDL Web 8.5 + DXA 2.O for Java. Is it available somewhere the API for the CIS? We want to retrieve the keywords from a component that it's linked to a dynamic component presentation, but keyword info is not populated.

We use postman to call to the model service:

http://slaws2cds9001.myserver.com:8189/EntityModel/tcm/5/593-721

However, we don't get the keyword info:

[image]

We are using `contentProvider.getEntityModel("593-721", localization)`

When accessing to the PageModel with the content related to the page, we get the keyword info. Keywords are in a publishable category and the category is published. In fact, when the component is related with the page, we can get the information.

Comment: It’s not completely clear to me what you are asking for.

Comment: Are the Keywords in a publishable Category? If so, is the Category actually published? If so, can you try what happens if you make the Category non-publishable and re-publish the DCP (so that static, CM-side expansion should happen)?

Comment: For clarity: the DXA Model Service should provide the full Keyword Model Data (if Keyword expansion is properly configured). If not, there may be a bug in the DXA Framework.  It should not be needed to do separate roundtrips to CIS to retrieve the Keyword data; the entire purpose of the DXA Model Service is to prevent multiple roundtrips.

Comment: Keywords are in a publishable category and the category is published. In fact, when the component is related with the page, we can get the information. However when using a dynamic component template, the KeywordModelData is not populated. I can not make the category non-publishable because indeed we need that it's publishable for static content pages. By the way, is there any API information?

Comment: OK, that starts to sound like a bug in the DXA Model Service. Please report it on [GitHub](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-model-service/issues).

Comment: https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v10/GUID-497B5657-6F9F-4EC3-9558-9A61CE7BF6A1

Comment: BTW: Can you update the title of the Question? It currently really does not explain what the question is about.

Comment: I report it to GitHub, but nobody said anything. To whom may I address that?

Comment: See the "Support" section in the [README on GitHub](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-model-service) for communication channels.

Comment: A new dxa-model-service was provided to us, and now this is solved.

Comment: @tfinez we are facing the exact same issue. Was the new version provided as a hotfix? Also could you share the version number of the model service that fixes this issue?

Comment: The fix is available at this commit https://github.com/sdl/dxa-model-service/commit/77c2043ba690ae15f3efee9c3f598cb7bd79a4e8, there's no update version so we just override the jar dxa-model-service-controller-2.0.0.jar  in the service sdl/model/services/model-service/